# Calendar reminder not working for onePlus Device

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap-plugins, phonegap

I am using cordova plugin "cordova-plugin-calendar" to add reminder events to the calendar from my cordova application. For all other device it is working as expected. In OnePlus device the event is getting added first then if we refresh the calendar or check the calendar in some time, the event is getting disappeared. I don't know why it is happening only in OnePlus device. Have any of you faced this kind of issue?.Any help in sorting out this issue would be much appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: Android version ?

Comment: android 8.1.0 Oreo